# Время работы программы

Tags: c

Подскажите, как подсчитать время выполнение данной программы. С GetTickCount не получается, выдает одинаковое время в начале и в конце.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int poisk (int kluch, int n, int *mas)
{
int a=0;
while(mas[a]!=kluch)
       {
           a++;
       }
       if (a < n)
       {
       printf("poisk proshel udachno\n");
       return a;
       }
       else
       {
       printf("poisk proshel neudachno\n");
       return -1;
       }
}

main()
{     
  int time_beg = GetTickCount();
  printf("%d\n\n", time_beg);
  int mas[2000]={0};
  int i, j, kluch=1111, k=0, n=2000, c=0, a=0, s, t;

  for (i=0; i<2000; i++)
       {
       mas[i]=rand();
       }

      mas[1999]=1111;
      mas[2000]=1111;

      /*for (i=0; i<2000; i++)
      {                    
         printf("%d. %d\n ", i,  mas[i]);
      }*/

  a=poisk(kluch, n, mas);
  if (a!=-1)
  printf(" %d\n\n", a);

  int time_end = GetTickCount();
  printf("%d\n\n", time_end);

  float time=(time_end-time_beg)/1000.;      
  printf("vremya vypolneniya:%fc", time);

getchar();
}
```

Comment: Если выдает одно и тоже время, значит код работает слишком быстро. Обычно помогает  прогон кода несколько раз. То есть, заверните содержимое main  в цикл и запустите его 1000 раз. Потом просто поделите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код выполняется быстрее одного тика.

Прогоните код в цикле N раз, и замерьте общее время. Подберите N достаточно большим (несколько миллионов?).

Попробуйте также использовать таймер получше. Например, [`gettimeofday`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468834/276994).